# android EditTextPreference onclick

Tags: android, onclick, preferences

i'm making a settings activity and i want to let user picks sound notification. Im using this to do it:

```
EditTextPreference dataPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("opcion3");

        dataPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
                Ajustes.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);          
                return true;
            }
          });
```

But when I click the EditTextPreference it shows a editbox with OK and cancel, and inmediatly it shows list of notification sounds.

How can i make it only shows the notifications sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use EditTextPreference?
Use  RingtonePreference or create custom Preference.

```
<RingtonePreference 
    android:key="notification_sound" 
    android:ringtoneType="notification" 
    android:title="Notification Sound" 
    android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
    android:showDefault="true" 
    android:showSilent="true" />
```